# Why does this code not work in my browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I run the following code in my browser (chrome) it doesn't work. However, when running this code in the stackoverflow preview compiler it works. Can somebody explain to me why ?

The code is supposed to change the background color of a div element.

My goal is to change the color of div using js. I also tried changing the value of a label and that didn't work either. The JS works without changing color( or text ) because it triggers an alert at the end. The code is also called after the document was loaded successfully.

```js
function load() {
  var div = document.getElementById('div1');
  var label = document.getElementById("label");

  // div.style.background = "green";
  // label.value = "ml";

  alert("hi");
}

document.addEventListener(load, load());
```

```css
body {
  background: #24313E;
  font-family: arial;
  color: #F2F2F4;
}

#div1 {
  background: red;
  width: 400;
  height: 400;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  hover me
</div>
<label id="label">hi</label>
```

Comment: Try `"DOMContentLoaded"` instead of `"load"`.

Comment: It works becase load() is called and the HTML code is already loaded

Comment: Also, a label doesn't have a value, so you can't change it. You probably meant to change its innerHTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass a function reference to document.addEventListener.
Also the event name you want is "DOMContentLoaded"

ie use **`document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", load);`** instead of `document.addEventListener("load", load());`

I think the reason why it works on Stackoverflow is because when load() is called the html part is already loaded so the selectors work

Comment: Also, `"load"` or `"DOMContentLoaded"` as a **String** instead of a variable reference.

Comment: Yeah that was it. Thank you!